# Status 501 - Method Not Implemented - when use Backbone

Tags: backbone.js, internal-server-error

When I send a POST method to a valid URL with Backbone, the server is returning this:

```
Method Not Implemented

POST to /clientes/login not supported.
```

What can it be?

EDIT: If I use a `form` with `method="post"` without `Backbone` the server is returning `Login Successfully`, like it has to do.

Thank you!

Comment: The developers of the service haven't started coding it?

Comment: That is not a backbone issue. The problem resides backend side, most probably the endpoint you are trying to call doesn't exist yet, or is programmed to fail immediately with that error. Or maybe it accepts only GET. Talk with backend guys.

Comment: If I use a form with method="post" without Backbone the server is returning Login Successfully, like it has to do.

Answer (score 0):

The URL may be valid, but that doesn't mean the server it is on supports whatever http method you are sending it with. In this case it seems the server does not have any support for POST. So you can not use POST on that server until the server is built to handle it. Try contacting who ever is in charge of the server.

Comment: But the server supports a post request in this URL. If a send a form from normal HTML the user is loggin. But when I use Backbone requisition, the server is returning this error.